# Condition for an python panda dataframe using an List with range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create an if conditions in a data frame that includes a list with a range between the elements?  I want a new smaller data frame that is in a range of certain values. Like `x` element of `[2,4]` and save it in a new data frame.

For example:

```
x y

1 4 
2 7
3 8
4 11
5 -15
6 13
```

My new table should be:

```
df[df[x] <= [2,4]]

x y
2 7
3 8 
4 11
```

I tried the following:

```py
df[df['time']<=[1212,1220].to_csv(path_or_buf=DATAFILE_OUTPUT, index=True, sep='\t', columns=out_columns, decimal='.')
```

But got a syntax error:

> `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolean mask:

```
df = df[df['x'].between(2,4)]
print (df)
   x   y
1  2   7
2  3   8
3  4  11
```

It working same like 2 conditions chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df = df[(df['x'] >= 2) & (df['x'] <= 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried both versions and in both cases everything no error occurred. Before I tried something similar to your version but I got the message 
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]: df[(df['time'] >= 1212 & df['time'] <= 1220)]. So it seems I forget the placement of the brackets.